# Why do most rotary potentiometers have an opening?

Tags: potentiometer

Is this opening not a bad thing because dust can get in? I'm thinking about putting a piece of tape on it.
[image: picture of opening]

Comment: But could those pins not be on top of the board?

Comment: How much did you pay for it? Because if you triple that you'd get nice sealed pot.

Comment: No, because the coal strip is on the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is to do with manufacturing process. Most low cost pots have a carbon track that has been deposited onto some kind of fibre board, which the wiper mechanism and cover attach onto. They are designed to be cheap and easy to put together. You can also get sealed pots, but they cost several times more:

[10k standard pot](http://be.farnell.com/bi-technologies-tt-electronics/p160knp-0qc20a10k/panel-pot-10k-log/dp/1760787)

[10k sealed pot](http://be.farnell.com/bourns/3310y-001-103l/potentiometer-10k/dp/9353976)

The gap is handy for squirting cleaning fluid into, though.

Answer (score 2):

The more common technical reason is for cooling with restricted convection air flow.

Many slider substrates are simply metalized films with power ratings of only 0.1 to 0.2W and the plastic film is a thermal insulator so adding more restricted air flow when operating near rated power, will raise the plastic film temp and risk burnout or fusing the element.